# Recover a mongo database deleted by rm

Tags: mongodb, recovery, disaster-recovery, mongo-repair

My developer accidentally lost our database by a bash script, which turned out to run `rm -rf /*` (see [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/959707/database-accidentally-deleted-with-a-bash-script)). Thanks to **extundelete**, he just recovered the `/data/db/` folder:

[image]

However, he could not successfully load the database in Robo 3T; it looks quite empty here:

[image]

Here is the result of running `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all --repair`:

```
I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23018 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.7
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1b82c812a9c0bbf6dc79d5400de9ea99e6ffa025
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true, port: 27017 }, repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1553494202:818725][23018:0x7f6119074a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1553494202:818725][23018:0x7f6119074a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.1
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:832267][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 4/11366912 to 5/256
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:832674][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 5
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:898252][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 5 through 5
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:964880][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1553494203:999855][23018:0x7f6119074a40], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1553494203:999855][23018:0x7f6119074a40], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file _mdb_catalog.wt found, renamed to _mdb_catalog.wt.1
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 3824 processes, 65535 files. Number of processes should be at least 32767.5 : 0.5 times number of files.
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 47d8713d-ac61-4081-83bf-60209ad60a7d
W ASIO     [initandlisten] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase admin
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection admin.system.version
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-4352287918877967674. Not salvaging.
I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.version" }
I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
```

Does anyone understand what's happening? does anyone know how to recover this mongodb?

Answer (score -1):

There may be some permission issue with the restored files causing you the MongoDB startup failure.

***Reference Link:***

[WiredTiger "handle-open: open: File exists"](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/328)