# Restore mongoDB by --repair and WiredTiger

Tags: mongodb, recovery, disaster-recovery, wiredtiger, mongo-repair

We accidentally deleted the directory `rm -rf /data/db` 
which was our **MongoDB path**, and thanks to
**extundelete**, we recovered it and got the directory `/data/db`.

Here are our files in the directory, and the files was generated under MongoDB **version 3.4**.

[image]

Folder `diagnostic.data`:

[image: Folder diagnostic.data]

Folder `journal`:

[image: Folder journal]

## Step 1: try to run mongod as normal

**a)** We ran `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all` and `mongo`, and expected there should have a user-defined database `wecaXX`, **But, it did not show up.**

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.000GB
```

In Robo3T

[image]

**b)** Then I tried to run `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all --repair`. The result was:

```
2019-03-25T14:10:02.170+0800 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=23018 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.7
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 1b82c812a9c0bbf6dc79d5400de9ea99e6ffa025
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distmod: ubuntu1604
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { bindIpAll: true, port: 27017 }, repair: true, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db" } }
2019-03-25T14:10:02.191+0800 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected unclean shutdown - /data/db/mongod.lock is not empty.
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Detected data files in /data/db created by the 'wiredTiger' storage engine, so setting the active storage engine to 'wiredTiger'.
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 W STORAGE  [initandlisten] Recovering data from the last clean checkpoint.
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten]
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] **          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem
2019-03-25T14:10:02.194+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] wiredtiger_open config: create,cache_size=256M,session_max=20000,eviction=(threads_min=4,threads_max=4),config_base=false,statistics=(fast),log=(enabled=true,archive=true,path=journal,compressor=snappy),file_manager=(close_idle_time=100000),statistics_log=(wait=0),verbose=(recovery_progress),
2019-03-25T14:10:02.818+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1553494202:818725][23018:0x7f6119074a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1553494202:818725][23018:0x7f6119074a40], connection: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/WiredTiger.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-03-25T14:10:02.818+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file WiredTiger.wt found, renamed to WiredTiger.wt.1
2019-03-25T14:10:03.832+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:832267][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Main recovery loop: starting at 4/11366912 to 5/256
2019-03-25T14:10:03.832+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:832674][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 4 through 5
2019-03-25T14:10:03.898+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:898252][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Recovering log 5 through 5
2019-03-25T14:10:03.964+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message [1553494203:964880][23018:0x7f6119074a40], txn-recover: Set global recovery timestamp: 0
2019-03-25T14:10:03.998+0800 I RECOVERY [initandlisten] WiredTiger recoveryTimestamp. Ts: Timestamp(0, 0)
2019-03-25T14:10:03.999+0800 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger error (17) [1553494203:999855][23018:0x7f6119074a40], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt: handle-open: open: File exists Raw: [1553494203:999855][23018:0x7f6119074a40], WT_SESSION.create: __posix_open_file, 715: /data/db/_mdb_catalog.wt: handle-open: open: File exists
2019-03-25T14:10:04.000+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTiger message unexpected file _mdb_catalog.wt found, renamed to _mdb_catalog.wt.1
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: You are running this process as the root user, which is not recommended.
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]
2019-03-25T14:10:04.015+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. rlimits set to 3824 processes, 65535 files. Number of processes should be at least 32767.5 : 0.5 times number of files.
2019-03-25T14:10:04.020+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] createCollection: admin.system.version with provided UUID: 47d8713d-ac61-4081-83bf-60209ad60a7d
2019-03-25T14:10:04.034+0800 W ASIO     [initandlisten] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2019-03-25T14:10:04.036+0800 I COMMAND  [initandlisten] setting featureCompatibilityVersion to 4.0
2019-03-25T14:10:04.036+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] repairDatabase admin
2019-03-25T14:10:04.037+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Repairing collection admin.system.version
2019-03-25T14:10:04.040+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Verify succeeded on uri table:collection-0-4352287918877967674. Not salvaging.
2019-03-25T14:10:04.048+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten] build index on: admin.system.version properties: { v: 2, key: { _id: 1 }, name: "_id_", ns: "admin.system.version" }
2019-03-25T14:10:04.048+0800 I INDEX    [initandlisten]          building index using bulk method; build may temporarily use up to 500 megabytes of RAM
2019-03-25T14:10:04.055+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] finished checking dbs
2019-03-25T14:10:04.055+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] WiredTigerKVEngine shutting down
2019-03-25T14:10:04.056+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-03-25T14:10:04.057+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] Finished shutting down session sweeper thread
2019-03-25T14:10:04.140+0800 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2019-03-25T14:10:04.140+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-03-25T14:10:04.140+0800 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:0
```

**c)** After repairing I re-ran `mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /data/db --bind_ip_all`, it still showed **nothing** (the same result as step a)).

## Step 2: Use wiredTiger tool

Since that didn't work as I expected, I started to find any other tools or approach that may help me. 
Here is the link [Recovering a WiredTiger collection from a corrupt MongoDB installation](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/) which introduces how to use WiredTiger to recover collections.
And I decided to have a try.

I created a folder `db_backup` and put all my files into it. And I created a folder `wiredtiger-3.0.0` under `db_backup`.I installed `wiredtiger` in folder `wiredtiger-3.0.0`:

[image]

**a) To salvage the collection**

```
root@iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z:/data/db_backup/# cd ./wiredtiger-3.0.0
root@iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z:/data/db_backup/wiredtiger-3.0.0# ./wt -v -h ../db_for_wt -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R salvage collection-23--360946650994865928.wt
        WT_SESSION.salvage 100
```

Based on the article above, it means that we have successfully salvaged this collection.

## Error Occured:

**b) To dump the collection**

```
root@iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z:/data/db_backup/wiredtiger-3.0.0# ./wt -v -h ../../db_backup -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R dump -f ../collection.dump collection-23--360946650994865928
lt-wt: cursor open(table:collection-23--360946650994865928) failed: No such file or directory
```

Note that the command above was indeed ended without `.wt`.

I have checked my directory argument and I found no fault. In the picture, the file  `collection-23--360946650994865928.wt` **is right Here**.

[image]

The snapshot of `collection-23--360946650994865928.wt` just has been salvaged.

We could see some English or Chinese characters in it. And that data truly is from one of collection of database `wecaXX`.

[image]

## Questions:

**1)** Now, I'm stuck by dumping the collection. Does anyone know what's wrong with that?

**2)** `collection-23--360946650994865928.wt` contains our most important data. If we could not restore the whole database, extracting data from that file will be still very useful. However, if we do copy paste manually, not all the characters are well written; they still need to be decrypted. Does anyone know how to do that?

**3)** is it possible that we did not recover all the files (or the entire body of all the files) under `/data/db`?

**Any comment or answer will be appreciated!!**

Comment: what is the MongoDB version(x,y,z)?

Comment: As i am able to see that from your screenshot of Robo3T, only visible to  admin and local databases (system databases). There is no any user defined database available . Could you update the same things.

Comment: ,After connecting with mongo cell , can you run the command such as **show dbs;** and update the screenshot of that.

Comment: Same question asked twice https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/232972/recover-a-mongo-database-deleted-by-rm

Answer (score 0):

As per your screenshot of **Robo3T** where only showing the System database (i.e., **`admin`** & **`local`**). There is no any user defined database is available with your connected host.

Eventhough the files you have generated under the mongodb version is **3.4** & the starting of MongoDB db version is sppearing as **v4.0.7**.

I will somewhere guess that you have been loose your user created database.

Suppose that if user database wil be there then automatically it will after host connection with Robo 3T-1.2 tool.

For example as the screenshot of Robo 3T - 1.1 appears in my environment.

[image]

For verification you can also check with mongo shell, after connecting the mongo shell  you can check the command such as **show dbs;**

It will apears like that

```
> show dbs
DynamicsAX  0.006GB
ERP         0.086GB
admin       0.000GB
blog        0.000GB
config      0.000GB
enron       0.207GB
local       0.000GB
mflix       0.060GB
test        0.001GB
```

> Note:- Right Now, Before doing any rocket science first you have to
>   take mongodump of your data directory .

As per mention screenshot by you [here](http://www.alexbevi.com/blog/2016/02/10/recovering-a-wiredtiger-collection-from-a-corrupt-mongodb-installation/) the database **Recovery** is a user defined database.

As per your error mongodump error log

```
root@iZj6c0pipuxk17pb7pbaw0Z:/data/db_backup/wiredtiger-3.0.0# ./wt -v -h ../../db_backup -C "extensions=[./ext/compressors/snappy/.libs/libwiredtiger_snappy.so]" -R dump -f ../collection.dump collection-23--360946650994865928
lt-wt: cursor open(table:collection-23--360946650994865928) failed: No such file or directory
```

It's unable to mongodump successfully.

> Note: The mongodump will fail if you’re using a version of MongoDB <
>   3.2, as 3.2 is built against WiredTiger 2.7.

**After edit the question of OP**

> Now, I'm stuck during dumping the collection. Are there anything wrong
>   with me?

Yes, Because the `mongodump` not went successfully.

> In the collection-23--360946650994865928.wt, have we really got the
>   whole data? Even if we could not recover the database, Could we
>   extract data from these *.wt files?

As [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204480/how-to-restore-wt-backup-file-to-local-mongodb) already **`community wiki`**  has been updated the answer, the **`*.wt`** are binary data files used by the WiredTiger storage engine. Individual files are not usable as a standalone backup. If you want to take a file copy backup of a MongoDB dbPath you need to include all of the files using a [Supported File Copy Backup Method.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/#back-up-by-copying-underlying-data-files)

for further you ref [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216759/how-to-restore-from-wt-files) , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557319/how-to-restore-mongowt-engine-only-with-collection-0-wt-file) , [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/) , [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/204480/how-to-restore-wt-backup-file-to-local-mongodb) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

Comment: "I will somewhere guess that you have been loose your user created database" ==> but we do see our most-wanted data in `collection-23--360946650994865928.wt`, they are not lost.

Comment: My files were generated under MongoDB 3.4 or higher, The error is "No such file or directory". So I think there must be some other reasons for "dump error".

Comment: In one of your ref links.[How to restore from .wt files?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/216759/how-to-restore-from-wt-files)
Compared his files in `/db` He got a file `WiredTiger.turtle` that I didn't see in my folder
Would it be a cause?

Comment: I am not sure if the command `./wt dump` is as same as `mongodump`.So does it really related to `mongodump`?

Comment: The WiredTiger.turtle file contains information required by the WiredTiger storage engine to understand the other data files. It should be along with the WiredTiger all files.